# Angular 2 materials, autocomplete with remote data

Tags: api, angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

I'm using Angular 4 with Materials 2.

I have successfully created some autocomplete fields using an array of data. Here my controller:

```
sectorCtrl;
allSectors
filteredSectors: any;

constructor() {
  this.sectorCtrl = new FormControl();
  this.filteredSectors = this.sectorCtrl.valueChanges
    .startWith(null)
    .map(name => this.filterValues(name));
}

filterValues(val: string) {
  return val ? this.allSectors.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s.label)) : this.allSectors;
}
```

And my template:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Sectors" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="sectorsCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let value of filteredSectors | async" [value]="value" >
    {{ value.label }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

How can I adapt the code in order to use a remote API?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the remote data via `service` and assign the data to a variable, in your example it will be assigned to `allSectors`. Then it's usual business, running the filter on `allSectors`, if `allSectors` is an array of objects, than you have to specify on which property you want to run the filter. In my demo, I am doing it for `sector.name`.

You can use `displayWith` to control what value to show in input field.

HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <md-option *ngFor="let sector of filteredSectors | async" [value]="sector">
        {{ sector.name }}
    </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

TS:

```
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample implements OnInit{
  stateCtrl: FormControl;

  filteredSectors: any;

  allSectors;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.fetchData()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.allSectors = data.customers;
          this.filteredSectors = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
            .startWith(null)
            .map(val => val ? this.filter(val) : this.allSectors.slice());
        }
    );

  }

  filter(name) {
   return this.allSectors.filter(sector => new RegExp(`^${name}`, 'gi').test(sector.name)); 
  }

   displayFn(sector) {
      return sector ? sector.name : sector;
   }

}
```

Here's the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aa2NNOHdKhB7n8iJcQbT?p=preview).

Comment: I think (and I'm running into the same issue myself) that @Bagbyte wants to use the remote API to do the filter. So the data should be fetched on `valueChanges`